# Determine Position of Element in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, position

Im searching for a function that Returns the Position of an element in a dataframe.
- there is duplicates in the dataframe amongst the values
- dataframe About 10*2000
- the function will be applied on a dataframe using applymap()

```
# initial dataframe

    df = pandas.DataFrame({"R1": [8,2,3], "R2": [2,3,4], "R3": [-3,4,-1]})
```

> Example:
>
> get_position(2) is not clear as it could be either "R1" or "R2". I am
>   wondering if there is another way that python knows which Position the
>   element holds - possibly during the applymap() Operation

*Edit:*

df.rank(axis=1,pct=True)

*EDIT2:*

```
#intial dataframe

df_initial = pandas.DataFrame({"R1": [8,2,3], "R2": [2,3,4], "R3": [-3,4,-1]})
```

*step1)*

```
df_rank = df_initial.rank(axis=1,pct=True)
```

*step2)*

```
# Building Groups based on the percentage of the respective value

    def function103(x):

        if 0.0 <= x <= 0.1:
            P1.append(get_column_name1(x))
            return x
        elif 0.1 < x <= 0.2:
            P2.append(get_column_name1(x))
            return x
        elif 0.2 < x <= 0.3:
            P3.append(get_column_name1(x))
            return x
        elif 0.3 < x <= 0.4:
            P4.append(get_column_name1(x))
            return x
        elif 0.4 < x <= 0.5:
            P5.append(get_column_name1(x))
            return x
        elif 0.5 < x <= 0.6:
            P6.append(get_column_name1(x))
            return x
        elif 0.6 < x <= 0.7:
            P7.append(get_column_name1(x))
            return x
        elif 0.7 < x <= 0.8:
            P8.append(get_column_name1(x))
            return x
        elif 0.8 < x <= 0.9:
            P9.append(get_column_name1(x))
            return x
        elif 0.9 < x <= 1.0:
            P10.append(get_column_name1(x))
            return x
        else:
            return x
```

*step3)*

```
# trying to get the columns Name of the the respective value
# my idea was to determine the Position of each value to then write a function

    def get_column_name1(x)

#to return the values column Name
```

*step 4)*

```
# apply the function

P1=[]
P2=[]
P3=[]
P4=[]
P5=[]
P6=[]
P7=[]
P8=[]
P9=[]
P10=[]
P11=[]
df_rank.applymap(function103).head()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If need index or columns names by value in DataFrame use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for positions and then select all index or columns values converted to numpy array:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"R1": [8,2,3], "R2": [2,3,4], "R3": [-3,4,-1]})

i, c = np.where(df == 2)
print (i, c)
[0 1] [1 0]

print (df.index.values[i])
[0 1]

print (df.columns.values[c])
['R2' 'R1']
```

EDIT:

```
i, c = np.where(df == 2)

df1 = df.rank(axis=1,pct=True)
print (df1)
         R1        R2        R3
0  1.000000  0.666667  0.333333
1  0.333333  0.666667  1.000000
2  0.666667  1.000000  0.333333

print (df1.iloc[i, c])
         R2        R1
0  0.666667  1.000000
1  0.666667  0.333333

print (df1.where(df == 2).dropna(how='all').dropna(how='all', axis=1))
         R1        R2
0       NaN  0.666667
1  0.333333       NaN
```

Or:

```
out = df1.stack()[df.stack() == 2].rename_axis(('idx','cols')).reset_index(name='val')
print (out)
   idx cols       val
0    0   R2  0.666667
1    1   R1  0.333333
```

EDIT:

Solution for your function - need iterate by one column DataFrame created by reshape and extract Series.name, what is same like column name:

```
def get_column_name1(x):
    return x.name
```

---

```
P1=[]
P2=[]
P3=[]
P4=[]
P5=[]
P6=[]
P7=[]
P8=[]
P9=[]
P10=[]
P11=[]

def function103(x):

    if 0.0 <= x[0] <= 0.1:
        P1.append(get_column_name1(x))
        return x
    elif 0.1 < x[0] <= 0.2:
        P2.append(get_column_name1(x))
        return x
    elif 0.2 < x[0] <= 0.3:
        P3.append(get_column_name1(x))
        return x
    elif 0.3 < x[0] <= 0.4:
        P4.append(get_column_name1(x))
        return x
    elif 0.4 < x[0] <= 0.5:
        P5.append(get_column_name1(x))
        return x
    elif 0.5 < x[0] <= 0.6:
        P6.append(get_column_name1(x))
        return x
    elif 0.6 < x[0] <= 0.7:
        P7.append(get_column_name1(x))
        return x
    elif 0.7 < x[0] <= 0.8:
        P8.append(get_column_name1(x))
        return x
    elif 0.8 < x[0] <= 0.9:
        P9.append(get_column_name1(x))
        return x
    elif 0.9 < x[0] <= 1.0:
        P10.append(get_column_name1(x))
        return x
    else:
        return x
```

---

```
a = df_rank.stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).to_frame().apply(function103, axis=1)
```

---

```
print (P4)
['R3', 'R1', 'R3']
```

Comment: Thank you for you fast Response! Let's say I am modifying my dataframe with the rank function. That way i have the same values in every row. Is there a way that I can only Display the np.where(df==x) for a single row, so that i get just one pair of coordinates? (see edit in Question)

Comment: @DieterMueller - So you need output like one column? Or both columns and then apply rank function like `cols = df.columns.values[c]` and then `df[cols].rank(axis=1,pct=True)`?

Comment: I initally have a dataframe that contains values ranging from About [-0,05;+0,05]. I am then applying the .rank() function to get the pct-values on the x axis. My next step where i am stuck at the Moment is when i am trying to work with the df.rank() to retrieve the initial values from the initial df. that is why I am trying to determine the Position in the df.rank() to then refer to the initial df. both dataframes measure 10*2000.

Comment: @DieterMueller - Please check edit. It is a bit problematic, what is expected output?

Comment: okay. and how do i get the value of the inital dataframe (df) after ur last step? i mean after eliminating all the other values but one in each row. In this case. so in the end I would like to refer to the columns Name in the inital dataframe based on the percentage value in the df.rank(). can you follow or is my Explanation lacking Information? thank you!

Comment: @DieterMueller - Thank you, so output are lists? Not DataFrame?

Comment: @DieterMueller - It is ugly, but possible, check edited answer.

Comment: hey there, exactly! lists as Outputs are perfect :-) Thank you so much for taking that much time to help me out. I have been trying for days (i am new to python - yet no excuse). I really appreciate that. have a great day :-)